# Usage of Biztalk SAP Adapter without Biztalk Server to connect .NET and SAP

Tags: .net, adapter, biztalk, sap-erp, saprfc

Is it possible to use the **Biztalk adapter pack** whithout a **Biztalk** installation (Biztalk license is available)?

I want to use the Biztalk Adapter for **SAP** RFC calls within a **.NET Application** (as a replacement of the **SAP Connector for .NET**, which is unfortunately no longer maintained by SAP and I can't use third-party products like "**ErpConnect**").

Does this idea make sense or not?

This question can be also seen in conjunction of my question concerning connecting SAP and Microsoft ([Microsoft and SAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198168/microsoft-and-sap))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adapters in the Biztalk adapter pack are build on the WCF LOB adapter SDK, so it's possible to use them without a Biztalk Server installation. I think you should take a look at the SAP tRFC Client sample from Microsoft on how to implement your solution. It's located at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/cc196386.aspx.

Comment: You still need a BizTalk license, even if don't need an BizTalk server installation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of SAP Connector for .NET, which will still be supported for quite some years: https://support.sap.com/connectors