# How to pull/push data from/to existing SAP system?

Tags: .net, connector, sap-basis, sap-dotnet-connector

I need to connect to ABAP-based SAP system, to pull/push data to/from that system.

I downloaded SAP PDK for .NET, build a solution using it, but this requires Portal Runtime for .NET to be installed on server, and this cannot be done, because SAP server is a Solaris one!

Also, I've checked existing solutions, but all of them use VS.NET 2003, to create what is called SAP Connector Proxy?

So, is there a way to connect to SAP system apart from using VS.NET 2003?

**[Update]**
Have any one checked this before, [**NCo**](http://williamvanstrien.blogspot.com/2010/12/sap-connector-for-microsoft-net-30.html).  It's a SAP .NET connector for .NET 3.0?!

Comment: Did nit try NCo, it seems to be pretty new, If you try it it would be interesting to know your impressions.

Comment: It's a good one, I already connected to SAP server using it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft and SAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198168/microsoft-and-sap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET 3.0](http://williamvanstrien.blogspot.com/2010/12/sap-connector-for-microsoft-net-30.html) is already there as an official SAP .NET connector.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to customize the SAP part, try to investigate PI, you can enable SAP.NET bidirectional communication via simple HTTP messages containing the data to exchange as n attachment. Very easy and stable way to go in my opinion.

Comment: What do you mean by "customize the SAP part"?

Comment: I mean if you can add some infrastructure in the SAP part to realize the data exchange. In this case you need to write some abap and to configure some PI channel on the SAP system.

Comment: In this case you can try the WCF Lob Adapter and teh BizTalk adapter pack:http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/adapter-pack.aspx despite the name you can use the components even without biztalk. This ption I investigate in the past but then I changed to the one I suggested, so I did not try that solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create webservices in the Sap environment. We use them extensively for CRUD of all sorts of data. I believe it's called XI Services, and you can find some information about it [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/9b/dad1ae3908ee44a5caf57e10918be9/content.htm).

The Sap analysts work in ABAP and send us ( .NET 4.0 developers working on VS2010 ) the wdsl's, all we have to do is integrate them into our solution like any other webservice.